How is chat_history style input created in prompt flow in Azure
In Azure Prompt Flow, the template for QnA contains a chat_history input. It seems it's read-only. How is such type of input created? When I click on add input, I don't see a way to create such type of input. All I see are fields for name, type and value.
The following is the code for the llm which uses chat_history. I am not able to understand where it's declared that chat_history has inputs and outputs fields and how is chat_input updated.
system: 
* Given the following conversation history and the users next question,rephrase the question to be a stand alone question.
If the conversation is irrelevant or empty, just restate the original question.
Do not add more details than necessary to the question.

chat history: 
{% for item in chat_history %} 
user: 
{{ item.inputs.chat_input }} 
assistant: 
{{ item.outputs.output }} 
{% endfor %}

Follow up Input: {{ chat_input }} 
Standalone Question:


